# How to hide inline text in div-block using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would like to hide some text inside a div-block, but I don't want to hide the whole div element, because there are other elements inside, which I need.

Please suggest a solution using jquery.

Comment: Can you please show some sample HTML? Can you put the text in question in a child span or div and then hide that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the text in a span, and hide *that*

Depending on the structure it could be something like this

```
<div id="yourDivId">
   <span>Hi There</span>
</div>

$("#yourDivId span:first").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by putting that code in a span. and hiding that span will hide that text only. not the whole div.

HTML:

```
<div id="whole">
  <span class="text">your text goes here</span>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".text").hide();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your html structure, here is my suggestion.

```
<div class="parent">
  <p class="children">Some text here</p>
</div>

$(".children").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Identify the elements that you want to hide. Wrap them with any div or span with unique id. So, you can hide with jQuery as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Span is the best way to divide the block level elements. Use span for the different section of the text you want to segregate and hide/show the span using jquery.

```
<div>
 <span class="show"> text1 </span> <span class="hide"> text2 </span> <span class="show"> text3 </span>
</div>

<script>
$(".hide").hide();
</script>
```